# How to get text from table like object via Selenium? (but not actually a table)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

Given the following "table" in Power BI web:

[table like object in Power BI Web with lists of Users and their emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MXIY.png)

I need Selenium to go row by row and extract the email and name of the individuals. Table rows may vary.

I've managed to get 1 email value out as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='artifactContentList']/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span")
element.text
```

However, this is tied to a specific row. Other rows would be as follows:

```
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/span
```

Here's the HTML of the "table" (includes only 1st row)

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport cdk-virtual-scroll-orientation-vertical ng-star-inserted" id="artifactContentList" itemsize="50" maxbufferpx="400" minbufferpx="400">
<div class="cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
<!----><!----><!---->
<div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" cdkmonitorsubtreefocus="" class="row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
   <!----><!----><!----><!---->
   <div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
      <!---->
      <user-details-host _ngcontent-thn-c41="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="col col-creator ng-star-inserted" role="cell" style="width: 432px;">
         <user-details _nghost-thn-c50="">
            <!---->
            <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-image ng-star-inserted">
               <!----><!---->
               <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-icon-circle ng-star-inserted" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
                  <!---->
                  <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="font-size: 10.08px;">GE</div>
                  <!---->
               </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
            <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-info ng-star-inserted">
               <!---->
               <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-name ng-star-inserted">Dashboard Name Here</div>
               <!---->
            </div>
         </user-details>
      </user-details-host>
   </div>
   <!----><!----><!---->
   <div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
      <!----><span _ngcontent-thn-c41="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="col col-emailAddress ng-star-inserted" role="cell" title="email@onmicrosoft.com" style="width: 385px;">email@onmicrosoft.com</span>
   </div>
   <!----><!----><!---->
   <div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
      <!----><span _ngcontent-thn-c41="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="col col-permissions ng-star-inserted" role="cell" title="Member (Owner)" style="width: 132px;">Member (Owner)</span>
   </div>
   <!----><!----><!---->
   <div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
      <!---->
      <update-permissions-context-menu _ngcontent-thn-c39="" class="context-menu ng-star-inserted" menuicon="pbi-glyph-more">
         <!---->
         <mat-menu class="">
            <!---->
         </mat-menu>
      </update-permissions-context-menu>
   </div>
   <!---->
</div>
<!----><!----><!---->
<div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" cdkmonitorsubtreefocus="" class="row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
<!----><!----><!----><!---->
<div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
   <!---->
   <user-details-host _ngcontent-thn-c41="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="col col-creator ng-star-inserted" role="cell" style="width: 432px;">
      <user-details _nghost-thn-c50="">
         <!---->
         <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-image ng-star-inserted">
            <!----><img _ngcontent-thn-c50="" alt="User profile image" src="blob:https://app.powerbi.com/f999999-9999-999-9a99-b977b9b59886" class="ng-star-inserted" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"><!---->
         </div>
         <!---->
         <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-info ng-star-inserted">
            <!---->
            <div _ngcontent-thn-c50="" class="user-name ng-star-inserted">John Doe</div>
            <!---->
         </div>
      </user-details>
   </user-details-host>
</div>
<!----><!----><!---->
<div _ngcontent-thn-c40="" class="fluent-cell ng-star-inserted" role="cell">
<!----><span _ngcontent-thn-c41="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="col col-emailAddress ng-star-inserted" role="cell" title="jdoe@onmicrosoft.com" style="width: 385px;">jdoe@onmicrosoft.com</span>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `find_elements` for multiple web elements.

and if you look into the xpath pattern that you have  :

```
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span
//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/span
```

you would see a sequence here.

`div[2]` then `div[3]` and `div[4]`

Now what you can do is to perform xpath indexing  :

```
div[{count}]
```

**sample code  :**

```
counter = 1
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//[@id='artifactContentList']/div[1]/div[{counter}]/div[2]/span"):
    print(element.text)
    counter = counter  + 1
```